# PHP and MySQL: Filter results based in dates in second column

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have one MySQL table with Hotel Rooms. I need to find rooms that are not ocuppied for example on '2018-05-18' or'2018-05-19'

```
"TABLE ROOMS"
+--------+--------------------------------+----------+-

| IDROOM|             TITLE               | CATEGORY   |

+--------+--------------------------------+----------+-

| 50      | Nice room with cable and wifi | Double Room |

| 51      | Small room with jacuzzy       | Single Room |

| 52      | Small room with balcony       | Triple Room | 

| 53      | Small room with 2 beeds       | Double Room |
```

and a second MYSQL table with the ID of the rooms and dates where are occupied (each line has one day only... for example idroom 15, occupiedate 2018-04-06, idroom 15, occupieddate 2018-04-07 etc):

```
"TABLE DATES"

+---------+--------+-------------------------+

|   ID    | IDROOM|             OCCUPIEDDATE  |

+---------+--------+-------------------------+

|    1    |   50   |           2018-04-07    |

|    2    |   50   |           2018-04-08    |

|    2    |   51   |           2018-05-08    |
```

I have this SQL Sentence:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.idroom FROM rooms r, dates rd WHERE r.category = 2 AND rd.idroom=r.idroom AND rd.occupieddate NOT IN ( '2018-04-07','2018-04-08' )
```

but it still shows me results that are occupied for example room 50.

What should I do?

Comment: Is `OCCUPIEDDATE` a date or character field?

Answer (score 1):

Your dates table probably also lists room 50 with dates that don't match those two.  I would reverse it:

```
SELECT rooms.idroom FROM rooms WHERE category = 2 AND rooms.idroom NOT IN ( SELECT dates.idroom FROM dates WHERE occupieddate IN ('2018-04-07','2018-04-08'));
```

Comment: you're missing the closing bracket

Comment: Thank you @SimonR

Comment: i would use table aliases or use fully quantified column names (like rooms.idroom)  because idroom is in both tables.. And because the inner SQL has acces to the outer SQL columns..MySQL could select the wrong column for the inner SQL.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news here, but..... I have a tinge of a doubt that the answer will be marked as solved.